Flutter Flame, Make enemy shoot projectiles slower
`I have a plant that shoots bullets when a player is within range. I added the shoot function on the onUpdate of the plant and the plant is shooting bullets in a stream...i want it sparsly maybe like one or two in a few seconds if that makes sense.

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    if (!gotStomped) {
      _updateState();
      _shoot();
    }
    super.update(dt);
  }

  void _shoot() {
    if (playerInRange()) {
      moveDirection = lerpDouble(moveDirection, tragetDirection, 0.1) ?? 1;

      current = State.attack;

      double playerOffset = (player.scale.x > 0) ? 0 : -player.width;
      double chickenOffset = scale.x > 0 ? 0 : -width;

      tragetDirection =
          (player.x + playerOffset < position.x + chickenOffset) ? -1 : 1;
      Bullet bullet = Bullet(
          position: Vector2(position.x, position.y),
          size: Vector2.all(16),
          tragetDirection: tragetDirection);

      parent?.add(bullet);
    } else {
      current = State.idle; // Back to idle state
    }
  }
}



You can use a SpawnComponent to do this, here is an example from the Space Shooter tutorial which is in the Flame docs:
class Player extends SpriteAnimationComponent
    with HasGameReference<SpaceShooterGame> {
  late final SpawnComponent _bulletSpawner;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    // Loading animation omitted

    _bulletSpawner = SpawnComponent(
      period: .2,
      selfPositioning: true,
      factory: (index) {
        return Bullet(
          position: position +
              Vector2(
                0,
                -height / 2,
              ),
        );

        return bullet;
      },
      autoStart: false,
    );

    game.add(_bulletSpawner);
  }

  void move(Vector2 delta) {
    position.add(delta);
  }

  void startShooting() {
    _bulletSpawner.timer.start();
  }

  void stopShooting() {
    _bulletSpawner.timer.stop();
  }
}

